# Node JS: Read from Stream then compress and create a compressed file using writable stream using fflate

Tags: node.js, stream, fflate

I have been trying to use the fflate library to compress a json file with streaming.But when i try to use fflate it is not working. couldnt find good examples of the the usage.This is sample snippet of the usage

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fflate = require('fflate');

const inputFilePath = './responses/output1.json';
const outputFilePath = './responses/output1.gz';

// Create a read stream for the input file
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });

// Create a write stream for the compressed output file
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath);

// Create a Gzip transform stream
const gzipStream = new fflate.Gzip({ level: 6 });

// Pipe the read stream through the Gzip stream to the write stream
readStream.pipe(gzipStream).pipe(writeStream);

// Event handlers for completion and errors
writeStream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log('File compression completed.');
});

writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error compressing file:', err);
});
```

This is the error being thrown
[image]

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Above snippet It is throwing some error in gzipStream.

Comment: And these errors are? Put some effort in your question/post when you expect help!

Comment: Sorry, Updated with error...please check

Comment: fflate does not support node streams. You can wrap it in a PassThrough stream.

Comment: I mean "Transform" stream. Not PassThrough stream.